# Conditional skip in google cloud-dataflow java pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have the code:

```
maxHotelEntry.apply("Convert to string", ToString.elements()).apply("Write to file", TextIO.write().to( config.getString( "gcs.checkPointLocation")).withoutSharding());
```

This PCollection can be empty, -2147483648(Integer.minvalue), 124526 (+value)

I do not want to write to checkPointLocation if it is empty or its value is less than 0.

One option is writing to GCS inside DoFn, but I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional step to filter out the elements you don't want to write

```
maxHotelEntry
    .apply("Convert to string", ToString.elements())
    .apply("Filter out elements", ParDo
          .of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
              public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String element = c.element();
                if ( /*perform your filter here*/ ) {
                  c.output(element);
                }
              }
          }))
    .apply("Write to file", TextIO.write().to( config.getString( "gcs.checkPointLocation")).withoutSharding());
```

Comment: my problem is maxHotelEntry contains only one value
this is the code for generating - maxHotelEntry = roomsTransformedData
    .apply("Get max HotelId", ParDo.of(new FindMaxHotelFn())).apply(Max.integersGlobally());

after applying filter, it is still writing empty to the file. 

I just want to skip the file write operation

Comment: as an alternate solution, i am reading the value from checkpointlocation and passing it to maxHotelEntry collection with side inputs, then comparing the two values and writing the maximum to checkPointLocation